Buck/boost inductor design calculation
I am designing a buck/boost converter with the following parameters:

Vin: 2.5 - 4.2 V
Vout: 3.3V
Iout Max: 1A
Fsw: 1250Khz (From Dtasheet Page 3)

Mine is a battery powered application.
The inductor design calculation in the datasheet is given below.

I believe the 0.3A is the allowed ripple current. Please correct me if I am wrong.
The datasheet also says this:

When I plug my values in the above equation I am getting L1 = 2.8uH and L2 = 3.1uH.

The datasheet says 2.2uH.
I have two questions:

Where did I go wrong?

How did they obtain the recommended value of 1.5uH to 4.7uH?


EDIT:1
I swapped the values of VIN1 and VIN2 as suggested by Andy. Below values are obtained for L1 and L2.


Have you tried using TI WebBench to get a starting point for your design?

I think you are misusing the formulas because they are producing minus signs for inductance. Below the formulas are these words for equation 3: -
In Equation 3 the minimum inductance value, L1 for step down mode 
operation is calculated. VIN1 is the maximum input voltage.

Hence to calculate L1 you have to use the maximum input voltage for Vin1.
For equation 4: -
In Equation 4 the minimum inductance, L2, for boost mode 
operation is calculated. VIN2 is the minimum input voltage.

In other words, Vin1 is not 2.5 volts but 4.2 volts and, Vin2 is not 4.2 volts but 2.5 volts.

How they obtained the recommended value of 1.5uH to 4.7uH

Different input voltage ranges and different output voltages require a wider spread of inductor values. The two values (1.5 μH and 4.7 μH) do not specifically apply to your use case.

I swapped VIN1 and VIN2 now I am getting L1 = 1.89uH and L2 = 1,62uH

@Confused those calculated inductance values are minimums, not exact values. Ripple current is the knob you can turn. So if you have more inductance than you originally calculated, you will just lower your ripple.

@Confused I'd probably choose a 2.2 uH inductor in that case.

May I know,why you choose 2.2 uH

@Confused because it has to be bigger than the larger of the two values calculated and 2.2 uH is a preferred value. If ripple current ends up being too high it may be necessary to use 2.7 uH or 3.3 uH but, you can't go below 1.89 uH (and that includes tolerancing). The 2.2 uH will need no more than a 10% tolerance on value. Bigger value inductors can be 20%.
